# Flyway Support for Hive or Impala

Tags: sql, hive, flyway, impala

does Flyway can support Hive or Impala JDBC Drivers?

I Googled around and found almost nothing (examples, problems) about this.

If i start a migration specifying the Hive Driver (previously downloaded in the /drivers path) I'm getting

```
"ERROR: Unable to autodetect JDBC driver for url: jdbc:hive2://HOSTNAME:10000/DATABASE;principal=hive/HOSTNAME@PRINCIPAL"
```

Thanks all in advance for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link, there is an Open issue for Hive support for flyway
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/142